# problems after upgrading xampp to 1.7.7

Tags: xampp, upgrade, php

i have upgraded my XAMPP server to 1.7.7, after that the file uploaded using the php move_uploaded_file function is not accessible from the network. It works OK in the server. But from a remote machine it shows there is not enough permission.I can see the files in the uploads folder but I can't copy,move, rename or preview it.

```
$isMove = move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],'uploads/'.$_FILES['image']['name']);
```

if I uses the copy function instead of the move_uploaded_file it works perfect. But i have used move_uploaded_files in many projects. Is there any fix for this problem.

Also a project using the zend optimizer is also not working after the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to set permissions of the directory so as PHP scripts can run with uid of user who has write permission or else in the case if the permissions are not such if they give write permission to user www-data they may give error.

Comment: there is no error in uploading images.I have XAMPP 1.7.7 installed in a Windows machine and i am working from a remote machine. The root folder is shared in the network, but i can see the updated files in the upload folder, but not able to preview, copy or rename it from the network. I was possible before the xampp upgrade.